# Read multiple RDS files in R

Tags: r, file, for-loop

I have a directory with multiple RDS files that I would like to read into R.

The files are saved as: "version_*Nr*_*MonthYear*.RDS". So for example
"version_5_August2022.RDS" or "version_4_June2021.RDS".

I want to keep the files name and load them into my global environment.
Is there a for loop or anything to load the files so I don't have to load them all individually like this:

`version_5_August2022 <- readRDS("~/version_5_August2022.RDS")`

Thank you! Any help is welcome.

Comment: Run `list.files`, extract the filename, then use use `assign`.

Comment: You can read the files names with list.files() and then use lapply() with readRDS() to load them.